# Using SDL(Simple DirectMedia Layer) Libraries in Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, sdl

i'm trying to include all SDL libraries that i have already installed and exist in '/usr/include/SDL' this directory contains all .h files

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main ()
{

SDL_Surface *screen=NULL ;

SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO !=0))
{

   printf("erreur");
   return 1 ;


}
screen=SDL_SetVideoMode (400,400,32,SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
if (screen== NULL)
{

printf("Unable to set video mode : %s \n",SDL_GetError() );
 return 1;
}
SDL_Flip (screen);
SDL_Quit ();
return 0;
 }
```

when i compile code above that exists in  main.c in terminal using this command:

```
gcc main.c -o program -LSDL
```

i get this :

```
axemaster@ubuntu:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ gcc main.c -o program -LSDL
/tmp/ccMx1per.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
main.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
main.c:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `SDL_SetVideoMode'
main.c:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
main.c:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `SDL_Flip'
main.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: `-LSDL` -> `-lSDL`.

Comment: Thank You !!! it worked didn't pay attention to that hahaha